# ¿Como mostrar la lista al cargar desde un inicio el componente?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy desarrollando vistas con listados que provienen de la api de woocommerce. La primera vista muestra un listado general, al pinchar en un campo de una fila se abre un modal con el detalle de esa fila, el problema que tengo es que no muestra el detalle nada mas abrirse el modal, se carga si haces una búsqueda en los filtros que e implementado. Desde la vista padre, al evento que abre el modal le paso el id de la categoria, las listas van filtradas por fecha de inicio y fin. No se por que no me carga la lista de detalles nada mas abrir el modal, no se si a parte del id de la categoria e de pasarle algo mas.

```
const Accounting = () => {

    const [accountingList, setAccountingList] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [searchStartDate, setSearchStartDate] = useState("2020-01-01");
    const [searchEndDate, setSearchEndDate] = useState("2023-06-16");
    const [currentPageWoocommerce, setCurrentPageWoocommerce] = useState(0);

   

    const [viewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled, setViewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

   
    const [showModalDetailSales, setShowModalDetailSales] = useState({show:false, id: -1, filter:{}});

    const openModalDetailSales = (id, accountingList) => {
        setShowModalDetailSales({show:true, id, filter: {}} )
        
    }
   
    ;
    const closeModalDetailSales = () => setShowModalDetailSales({show:false, id: -1,filter:{} });
 
    const fetchWooCommercePaginatedList = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        const filter = {
            page: currentPageWoocommerce,
            searchStartDate: searchStartDate,
            searchEndDate: searchEndDate
        };

        getCategoriesSummary(filter)
        .then((response:any)=>{
            console.log(`response: ${response}`);         
            setViewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled(response.has_more);
            let list:any[] = [];
            if (filter.page == 0) {
                list = response.items;
            } else {
                list = [...accountingList, ...response.items];
               
            }

            setAccountingList(list);
            
            console.log(list);

            setIsLoading(false);
        }).catch((error)  => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    const handleChangeStartDate = e => {
        setCurrentPageWoocommerce(0);   
        setSearchStartDate(e.target.value);
        setSearchEndDate(searchEndDate);
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            const filter = {
                page: 0,
                searchStartDate: e.target.value, 
                searchEndDate: searchEndDate,  
            };

            getCategoriesSummary(filter);
            updateTable()
        }, 800);
    } 


    const handleChangeEndDate = e => {
        setCurrentPageWoocommerce(0);   
        setSearchStartDate(searchStartDate);
        setSearchEndDate(e.target.value);
        setTimeout(() => {
            const filter = {
                page: 0,
                searchStartDate: searchStartDate, 
                searchEndDate: e.target.value,  
            };

            getCategoriesSummary(filter);
            updateTable()
        }, 800);
    } 

    //funcion ver más datos
    const handleShowMoreData = () => {
        setCurrentPageWoocommerce(currentPageWoocommerce + 1);
        fetchWooCommercePaginatedList();
    }

   const updateTable = () => {
    fetchWooCommercePaginatedList()
   }

   

  
    useEffect (() => {
       
        fetchWooCommercePaginatedList(); 
        updateTable()
        // openModalId();
    }, []);



   
  return (
    <>

    { showTabSales === true ?
        <>
        <Head>
            <title>Contabilidad - {appTitle}</title>
        </Head>

       <SectionMainFull>
            <SectionTitleLineWithButton icon={mdiAccountCreditCardOutline} title="Contabilidad" main>
              
            </SectionTitleLineWithButton>

        <CardBox className="p-6">
            
            <div className="mb-4 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 flex items-center justify-between flex-col-reverse md:flex-row gap-3">
            
                <ul className="flex items-center justify-between flex-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-center icofcv-tabs" id="Tab" data-tabs-toggle="#onTabContent" role="tablist">
                    <li className="mr-2" role="presentation">
                    {showTabSales === true ?
                        <button onClick={openTabSales} className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-800 border-teal-600 hover:border-teal-800" id="job-tab" data-tabs-target="#job" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="job" aria-selected="false">Ventas</button>
                        :
                        <button onClick={openTabSales}  className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 border-transparent hover:text-teal-800 hover:border-teal-800 " id="job-tab" data-tabs-target="#job" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="job" aria-selected="false">Ventas</button>
                    }
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-2" role="presentation">
                    {showTabPayments === true ?
                        <button onClick={openTabPayments} className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-800 border-teal-600 hover:border-teal-800" id="benefits-tab" data-tabs-target="#benefits" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="benefits" aria-selected="false">Pagos</button>
                        :
                        <button onClick={openTabPayments}  className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 border-transparent hover:text-teal-800 hover:border-teal-800 dark:hover:text-teal-300"  id="benefits-tab" data-tabs-target="#benefits" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="benefits" aria-selected="false">Pagos</button>
                    }
                    </li>
                </ul>
             
        </div>

        
            <div className="flex items-center my-2 md:mx-4 md:my-6 flex-wrap justify-start w-100 gap-4">
                            <div>
                            <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Fecha inicio</label>
                                <input
                                type="date"
                                value={searchStartDate}
                                placeholder="Buscar..."
                                className="w-72 me-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block p-2"
                                aria-label="Search"
                                onChange={handleChangeStartDate}
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div>
                            <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Fecha fin</label>
                                <input
                                type="date"
                                value={searchEndDate}
                                placeholder="Buscar..."
                                className="w-72 me-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block p-2"
                                aria-label="Search"
                                onChange={handleChangeEndDate}
                                />
                            </div>
                         
                    </div>

                   
        <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Categoría</th>
                    <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Artículos vendidos</th>
                    <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Importe</th>
                    <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Artículos</th>
                    <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Pedidos  </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
               
                <tbody>
                {isLoading && <Loader />}
                {accountingList.map((accounting) => (
                
                
                    <tr> 
                    <td data-label="key">
                        <button onClick={() => openModalDetailSales(accounting.category_id, accounting)} data-label="key" className="text-xs text-teal-600 hover:underline">{accounting.category_name}</button>
                    </td>
                    {console.log("campos", accounting.category_id)}
                    <td data-label="key" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{accounting.num_items_sold}</td>
                    <td data-label="key" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{formatNumbersUtils.formatNumber(accounting.net_sales)}</td>
                    <td data-label="description" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{accounting.num_products}</td>
                    <td data-label="description" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{accounting.num_orders} </td>
                   
                    </tr>
                   
                     ))} 
                     
                 </tbody>
                
                </table>
               
                <div className="p-3 lg:px-6 border-t border-gray-100 dark:border-slate-800">

                    {/* {viewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled === false ?
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end mx-3">
                    <button className="bg-transparent text-teal-600 text-sm active:bg-teal-700 py-2 outline-none focus:outline-none rounded underline" type="button" onClick={handleShowMoreData}>VER MÁS</button>
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div></div>

                    } */}
                </div>
               
                <ModalDetailSales showModalDetailSales={showModalDetailSales} closeModalDetailSales={closeModalDetailSales} updateTable={updateTable} />
              
        </CardBox>
      </SectionMainFull>
      </>
        :null
       
        }

{ showTabPayments === true ?
        <>
       
       <TabPaymentsAccounting openTab={openTab}/> 

       
      
      </>
        :null
       
        }
        </>
  )
}

Accounting.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <LayoutAuthenticated>{page}</LayoutAuthenticated>
}

export default Accounting

////modal

interface Props {

    showModalDetailSales: {
        show: boolean;
        id: number;
        filter: {}
    },
    closeModalDetailSales: () => void;
    updateTable: () => void;
}


export const ModalDetailSales: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalDetailSales, closeModalDetailSales, updateTable }) => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [detailSalesList, setDetailsSalesList] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [searchStartDate, setSearchStartDate] = useState("2020-01-01");
    const [searchEndDate, setSearchEndDate] = useState("2023-06-16");
    const [searchStatus, setSearchStatus] = useState("");
    const [currentPageWoocommerce, setCurrentPageWoocommerce] = useState(0);
    const [viewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled, setViewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled] = useState(false);

    const openTab = () => {
        setShowTabOrders(true)
        setShowTabItems(false)
    };

    const [showTabOrders, setShowTabOrders] = useState(true);
    const openTabOrders = () => {
        setShowTabOrders(true)
        setShowTabItems(false)


    }


    const [showTabItems, setShowTabItems] = useState(false);
    const openTabItems = (id) => {
        setShowTabItems(true)
        setShowTabOrders(false)
    }

    const [showModalDetailPaymentsOrder, setShowModalDetailPaymentsOrder] = useState({ show: false, id: -1 })
    const openModalDetailPaymentsOrder = (id) => setShowModalDetailPaymentsOrder({ show: true, id })
    const closeModalDetailPaymentsOrder = () => setShowModalDetailPaymentsOrder({ show: false, id: -1 })

    const fetchDetailsSalesPaginatedList = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const filter = {
            page: currentPageWoocommerce,
            searchStartDate: searchStartDate,
            searchEndDate: searchEndDate,
            status: searchStatus
        };
        getOrdersByCategory(filter, showModalDetailSales.id)
            .then((response: any) => {
                console.log(`response: ${response}`);
                setViewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled(response.has_more);
                let list: any[] = [];
                if (filter.page == 0) {
                    list = response.items;
                } else {
                    list = [...detailSalesList, ...response.items];
                }

                setDetailsSalesList(list);
                updateTable()
                console.log(list);

                setIsLoading(false);
            }).catch((error) => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            });
    }

    const filterChange = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const filter = {
                page: 0,
                searchStartDate: searchStartDate,
                searchEndDate: searchEndDate,
                status: searchStatus
            };

            getOrdersByCategory(filter, showModalDetailSales.id);
            fetchDetailsSalesPaginatedList()
            updateTable()
        }, 800);
    }

    const handleChangeStartDate = e => {
        setCurrentPageWoocommerce(0);
        setSearchStartDate(e.target.value);
        filterChange()

    }


    const handleChangeEndDate = e => {
        setCurrentPageWoocommerce(0);
        setSearchEndDate(e.target.value);
        filterChange()
    }

    const handleChangeStatus = e => {
        setCurrentPageWoocommerce(0);
        setSearchStatus(e.target.value)
        filterChange()
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchDetailsSalesPaginatedList()
        updateTable()
    }, []);

    //////////////////
    


    return (

        <>
            {isLoading && <Loader />}
            {showModalDetailSales.show ?
                <>
                    <div id="defaultModal" aria-hidden="true" className="fixed top-0 z-40 inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity "></div>
                    <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 w-full">
                        <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                            <CardBox className="w-screen m-8">
                                {/* Modal header */}
                                <div className="flex justify-between items-start py-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600 mb-4 px-6">
                                    {detailSalesList.slice(0, 1).map((detailSales) => (
                                        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{detailSales.category_name}</h3>
                                    ))}
                                    <button type="button" className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" onClick={closeModalDetailSales}>
                                        <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clipRule="evenodd"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                        <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="p-6">
                                    {showTabOrders === true ?
                                        <>

                                            <div className="mb-4 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 flex items-center justify-between flex-col-reverse md:flex-row gap-3">
                                                <ul className="flex items-center justify-between flex-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-center icofcv-tabs" id="Tab" data-tabs-toggle="#onTabContent" role="tablist">
                                                    <li className="mr-2" role="presentation">
                                                        {showTabOrders === true ?
                                                            <button onClick={openTabOrders} className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-800 border-teal-600 hover:border-teal-800" id="job-tab" data-tabs-target="#job" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="job" aria-selected="false">Pedidos</button>
                                                            :
                                                            <button onClick={openTabOrders} className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 border-transparent hover:text-teal-800 hover:border-teal-800 " id="job-tab" data-tabs-target="#job" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="job" aria-selected="false">Pedidos</button>
                                                        }
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li className="mr-2" role="presentation">
                                                       
                                                           
                                                                {showTabItems === true ?
                                                                    <button onClick={ openTabItems} className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-800 border-teal-600 hover:border-teal-800" id="benefits-tab" data-tabs-target="#benefits" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="benefits" aria-selected="false">Artículos</button>
                                                                    :
                                                                    <button onClick={openTabItems} className="inline-flex px-2 md:px-4 py-2 border-b-4 border-transparent hover:text-teal-800 hover:border-teal-800 dark:hover:text-teal-300" id="benefits-tab" data-tabs-target="#benefits" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="benefits" aria-selected="false">Artículos</button>
                                                                }
                                                           
                                                      
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="flex items-center my-2 md:mx-4 md:my-6 flex-wrap justify-between w-100 gap-2">
                                                <div className="flex">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Fecha inicio</label>
                                                        <input
                                                            type="date"
                                                            value={searchStartDate}
                                                            placeholder="Buscar..."
                                                            className="w-60 me-2 mr-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block p-2"
                                                            aria-label="Search"
                                                            onChange={handleChangeStartDate}
                                                        />
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div>
                                                        <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Fecha fin</label>
                                                        <input
                                                            type="date"
                                                            value={searchEndDate}
                                                            placeholder="Buscar..."
                                                            className="w-60 me-2 mr-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block p-2"
                                                            aria-label="Search"
                                                            onChange={handleChangeEndDate}
                                                        />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Estado</label>
                                                        <select

                                                            value={searchStatus}
                                                            placeholder="Buscar..."
                                                            className="w-60 me-2 mr-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block p-2"
                                                            aria-label="Search"
                                                            onChange={handleChangeStatus}
                                                        >
                                                            <option>Seleccionar estado</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-completed"}>Completado</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-pending"}>Pendiente</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-processing"}>En proceso</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-failed"}>Fallido</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-cancelled"}>Cancelado</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-refunded"}>Devuelto</option>
                                                            <option value={"wc-on_hold"}>En espera</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <input
                                                            type="text"
                                                            // value={searchEmployments}
                                                            placeholder="Buscar..."
                                                            className="w-60 me-2 mt-6 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block p-2"
                                                            aria-label="Search"
                                                        // onChange={handleChange}
                                                        />
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <BaseButton
                                                    data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"
                                                    // onClick={()=>openModal(-1)}
                                                    icon={mdiTrayArrowDown}
                                                    label="Descargar"
                                                    color="icofcv"
                                                    small
                                                    className="mt-6"
                                                />

                                            </div>

                                            <div className="overflow-auto" style={{ maxHeight: '400px', }}>
                                                <table>
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Fecha</th>
                                                            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Pedido #</th>
                                                            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Cliente</th>
                                                            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Tipo de cliente</th>
                                                            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Importe</th>
                                                            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Estado</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>

                                                    <tbody>
                                                        {isLoading && <Loader />}
                                                        {detailSalesList.map((detailSales) => (

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <button onClick={() => openModalDetailPaymentsOrder(detailSales.order_id)} data-label="key" className="text-xs text-teal-600 hover:underline">{dateUtils.utcToDate(detailSales.date_created)}</button>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td data-label="key" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{detailSales.order_id}</td>
                                                                <td data-label="key" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{detailSales.customer_name}</td>
                                                                <td data-label="description" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{detailSales.customer_type}</td>
                                                                <td data-label="description" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{formatNumbersUtils.formatNumber(detailSales.net_sales)}</td>
                                                                <td data-label="status">{statusColors(detailSales.status)}</td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                        ))}
                                                    </tbody>

                                                </table>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="p-3 lg:px-6 border-t border-gray-100 dark:border-slate-800 h-8 mt-0">
                                                {viewMoreWoocommerceDataDisabled === false ?
                                                <div className="flex items-center justify-end mx-3">
                                                    <button className="bg-transparent text-teal-600 text-sm active:bg-teal-700 py-2 outline-none focus:outline-none rounded underline" type="button" onClick={handleShowMoreData}>VER MÁS</button>
                                                </div>
                                                :
                                                <div></div>

                                            }
                                            </div>

                                            {/* <ModalDetailSales showModalDetailSales={showModalDetailSales} closeModalDetailSales={closeModalDetailSales} updateTable={updateTable} /> */}
                                            <ModalDetailPaymentsOrder showModalDetailPaymentsOrder={showModalDetailPaymentsOrder} closeModalDetailPaymentsOrder={closeModalDetailPaymentsOrder} />


                                        </>
                                        : null

                                    }

        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Tienes alguna forma de reducir el código del ejemplo? Es demasiado largo como para seguirlo fácilmente.